# If statement to find a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div onclick="showCustomerResultsTable();"
 class="csq-tab ui-state-default ui-corner-top"
 id="customers-tab">Customers</div>  

<div onclick="showParcelJourneySummary();"
 class="csq-tab ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-state-active"
 id="order-journey-summary-tab">Status History</div>
```

Using javascript how can I check which one of these have ui-state-active, because I need an `if` statement to check whether the ui-state-active is activated on status history and do something.

Comment: Are you willing/able to use a Javascript framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com)?

Comment: Yes not sure which version i have though

Comment: From the class names, I gather that you're already using jQuery UI. jQuery should already be at your disposal... No?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var statusHistory = document.getElementById('order-journey-summary-tab');

if(statusHistory.classList.contains('ui-state-active')) {
    // do stuff
}
```

or if you have jQuery

```
if($('#order-journey-summary-tab').hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can easily be checked with the new HTML5 classList API:

```
document.getElementById('customers-tab').classList.contains('ui-state-active');
// Will return true if element has class
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use the old way:

```
document.getElementById('customers-tab').className.indexOf('ui-state-active') != -1;
// Will return true if element has class
```

I would recommend using the [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) property in jQuery though!

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery's [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

Otherwise you need to check the `className` property of the element w/ plain ol' JavaScript.